# ¿Para que se utilizo este "operador de asignación", en esta línea de código?

Tags: java

Miren este es el codigo, la verdad no tiene mucha importancia que lo vean, pero lo dejo por si las dudas:

```
int filas=3;
int columnas=3;
int contador = columnas-(columnas-filas);
String resultado = "";

for( int j = 0; j < filas; j++ ){
  int tmp = 0;
  for( int i = 0; i < columnas; i++){
  // sumamos j+1 para que empieze en 1 y no en 0
  // y luego le sumamos la variable tmp
  resultado += "["+ ((j+1)+tmp) +"]";
  //tmp no sera solo igual a columnas
  // porque para 4 columnas fallaria
  tmp+=contador; 
  }
  resultado += "\n"; // salto de linea para el siguiente nivel
}
System.out.print(resultado);
```

La parte importante surge solamente con esta línea de código(que es parte del código anteriormente mostrado):

```
resultado += "\n"; // salto de línea para el siguiente nivel
```

¿Para que se utiliza el operador de asignación `+=`, si no hay ningún valor seguido de este, solamente hay un salto de línea `/n` ?

Comment: El operador `+=` añade a la variable de la izquierda lo que hay a la derecha. En este caso la variable es de tipo `String`, por lo que "añadir" no es sumar, sino _concatenar_. Es decir, concatenas un retorno de carro a lo que hubiera en la cadena.

Comment: Mas alla de la explicacion de abufalia, no entiendo tu duda.. vos mismo estas diiendo que esta asignando algo. Porque pensas que un salto de linea no es "algo"

Comment: ok , pero lo estoy concatenando o que estoy haciendo con ese salto de línea, yo no hice tal codigo, solo me lo pasaron y me surgio esa duda.

Answer (score 1):

Se podría decir que es un equivalente a la siguiente operación:
resultado = resultado + "\n";

Otro ejemplo seria: 
 `int num = 2; //declaras

num = num +2 ; //ahora sumas 2 y num = 4`

otra manera de realizar la sumatoria es:
 `num += 2;`

Solo que en tu caso estas concatenendo String.

espero que los ejemplos te hayan sido de ayuda.